# Laravel issue Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, loops, foreach, laravel-blade

Here I'm trying to loop supplier names using a foreach loop but I'm getting following error

```
<tbody style="font-size:small">

                    @foreach($material as $material)

                    <tr class="odd" role="row">

{!! Form::open(['route'=>'materialsupplier.store','class'=>'form-horizontal p-t-20']) !!}
                        <td>{{ $material->name }}<input type="hidden" value="{{ $material->id }}" name="mat_id"></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('sup_id') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">

                                <div >
                                    <select class="form-control js-cities" name="sup_id">
                                        <option value="" selected disabled>Select Supplier</option>
                                        @foreach ($supplier as $supplier)
                                         <option value="{{ $supplier->id}}">{{$supplier->company_name}}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
 {{ Form::submit('Save',['class'=>'far fa-trash-alt btn btn-info btn-sm btn-rounded m-b-1 m-l-5']) }}
                           </td>  
                        {!! Form::close() !!}      
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>
```

[image: error]

after that i chaged my code like this

```
<select class="form-control js-cities" name="sup_id">
 <option value="" selected disabled>Select Supplier</option>
    @foreach ($supplier as $supplier)
     <option value="{{ $supplier}}">{{$supplier}}</option>
     @endforeach
  </select>
```

output
[image: output]

controller

```
public function index()
    {
       $material = Material::all();
       $supplier = Supplier::all();

   return view('materialMgmt.material_suppliyer.create')->withMaterial($material)->withSupplier($supplier);
    }
```

How can I avoid getting this error?

Comment: first of all, array expression and value have the same name! please change it : `@foreach($material as $material)` and `@foreach ($supplier as $supplier)`

Comment: thank you, sir, your advice helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code as following and its worked

```
<select class="form-control js-cities" name="sup_id">
      <option value="" selected disabled>Select Supplier</option>
             @foreach ($supplier as $sup)
             <option value="{{ $sup->id}}">{{$sup->company_name}}</option>
             @endforeach
 </select>
```

Sir FatemehNB, Thank for your suggestion.